# How to visualize 2D or 3D Rotation matrices

Tags: lie-groups

How to visualize 2D or 3D Rotation matrices in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, can we preserve the manifold properties? Like geodesic distance?

Comment: Do you want to visualize the space of rotation matrices? If so, are you familiar with the more standard topological spaces that these spaces of rotations are diffeomorphic to?

Comment: @gsoldier There is an isometric correspondence between the 2D rotation matrices (equipped with the Frobenius norm) and a circle in $\Bbb R^2$ of radius $\sqrt{2}$, but it is unclear from the phrasing of your question whether this would count as "visualizing" the matrices.

Comment: I know basic topology. Can you offer more detailed hints or references? How do we build these isometric?@J.V.Gaiter @Ben Grossmann

Comment: Identifying $SO(2)$ (2D rotation matrices) with $S^1$ is a simple matter of sending rotation by $\theta$ to the point at angle $\theta$ from your starting point.

Comment: @gsoldier Is that what you mean by “visualizing” these matrices?